# How to make a connection between the models Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, migration, relationship

I had a need to make the connection in Ruby on Rails, where one model refers to another (which is something like the switch) in databases, it looks like this:

[image]

I believe this is a bit of a polymorphic connection, but little else.

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. As per [proper SO etiquette](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), you should show what you have tried and ask for assistance in improving your code or filling in the gaps. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing, including all error messages. Otherwise, [Google can help you](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution of this problem is as follows:

**Migration**

```
# db / schema.rb 
       create_table "switchs", force: true do | t | 
         # t.references :switch, polymorphic: true - in the migration 
         # t.references :item - migration 
         t.integer "switch_id" 
         t.string "switch_type" 
         t.integer "item_id" 
       end 
    
       create_table "options", force: true do | t | 
         t.string "title" 
         ... 
       end 
       create_table "items", force: true do | t | 
          t.string "name" 
          ... 
       end
```

Accordingly, the model itself will have immediately Switch 2 type of communication ***polymorphic:*** and ***has_many: through***

```
# app / models / switch.rb 
       class Switch <ActiveRecord :: Base 
         belongs_to :item 
         belongs_to :switch, polymorphic: true 
         ... 
       end
```

Model item refers to the model through ***source_type:*** and id in this model ***source: "switch"***

```
# app / models / item.rb 
class Item <ActiveRecord :: Base 
  has_many :switchs 
  has_many :options, through: :switchs, source_type: "Option", source: "switch" 
  has_many :photos, through: :switchs, source_type: "Photo", source: "switch" 
  ... 
end 

# app / models / option.rb 
class Option <ActiveRecord :: Base 
  has_many :items, through: :switchs 
  has_many :switchs, as: :switch 
  ... 
end
```

Well, the principle of operation of all the traditions of the rails =)

```
> item = Item.create (name: "Street") 
> option = Option.create (title: "Manhattan") 
> item.options.push option
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use link like belong_to,has_many in each model,to refer to their relation

```
class Concentrator < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :battery_voltage, :device_id
  belongs_to :project
end
```

the name after belongs_to is another table name or controller name without s
other relation links are:

belongs_to,
has_one,
has_many,
has_many :through,
has_one :through,
has_and_belongs_to_many,

you may refer to this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

like this.according to your database structure

Comment: I can not make a standard means of rails, everything is compact and beautiful. 
Yes, you can use for each option has_many * OPTION * through: relation_item, then I will have to create an additional two times tables ... But maybe there is some way that garazdo shorter?